# SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize as an ORM to my node js app and Mysql database , 
after following some tutorials i m adding this code to connect mysql to the node but after taping npm start i m getting this error : 
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

 // Option 1: Passing parameters separately
 const sequelize = new Sequelize('Education', 'root','', {
 host: '127.0.0.1',
 dialect: 'mysql'
 } );

  //test db 
 sequelize
.authenticate()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
 .catch(err => {
 console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

Comment: Do you have mysql server setup on your machine?

Comment: Do you have same error if you replace '127.0.0.1' with 'localhost'?

Comment: Problem solved i was using port : 3307 in phpMyadmin instead of 3306 ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved i was using port : 3307 in phpMyadmin instead of 3306

Answer (score 5):

FIX for Node.js use:

It looks as though the current version of sequelize (7) only works on Node.js versions `^12.22.0`, `^14.17.0` & `^16.0.0`.  `www.sequelize.org` says that some other versions may work as well.

Use NVM to install and switch to version 16.0.0:

If you don't already have node version manager you can install it with

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Then install version 16 with `nvm i 16.0.0` and then tell your application to use it with `nvm use 16.0.0`.

Answer (score 4):

Add `socketPath` in the dialect options

Example code snippet:

```js
// Option 1: Passing parameters separately
const sequelize = new Sequelize('Education', 'root', '', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
  }
});
```

Comment: I had the same error, and with your help it worked. But why do you have to put socketPath? Why doesn't it just work with host and dialect? In production do I have to leave the socketPath? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the **mysql** server.

Linux and Mac:

> service mysql restart

Windows:

Open the **Run** window by using the **Windows+R** keyboard.
Second, type **services.msc** and press **Enter**:
Find mysql and **restart** the service.

Comment: Thank you, restarting postgresql worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**the solution is just only Start Your Xampp Apache and MySQL Service.[image]**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33452505)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running XAMMP server on windows, first start apache server with MySQL

You get this error probably because your server is not running.

check your server and restart if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I have removed port option and issue is resolved.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'dbuser', 'pass', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    operatorAlias:false,
    logging:false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        idle: 30000,
        acquire: 60000,
    },
    
})
```

Comment: Removing the port option could work only in your set-up. As the author mentioned afterwards, on their set-up their port was different than the default, and thus was the connection error.